# Spark (Scala) Replace all values in string with new values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to spark, struck here by trying to replace values of string with new values.

```
Data in URL="a=1,
b=2,
c=3"
var header="a,b,c"
for (line <- Source.fromURL("/u/r/l").getLines) {
     if(header.contains(line.split("=")(0).toLowerCase().trim)) {
       header.replaceAll(line.split("=")(0).toLowerCase().trim,line.split("=")(1).toLowerCase().trim)
     }
      }
```

I am expecting my final output as

```
println(header)
1,2,3
```

How can I achieve this, when I run this, still getting `"a,b,c"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is assignment as

```
for (line <- Source.fromURL("/u/r/l").getLines) {
     if(header.contains(line.split("=")(0).toLowerCase().trim)) {
       header = header.replaceAll(line.split("=")(0).toLowerCase().trim,line.split("=")(1).toLowerCase().trim)
     }
}
```

You can do it more functionally as

```
Source.fromURL("/u/r/l").getLines.map(_.split("=")).map(line => header = header.replaceAll(line(0).toLowerCase().trim,line(1).toLowerCase().trim))
```

going one step further you can change the url to Map and apply the mapping as

```
val kv = Source.fromURL("/u/r/l").getLines.map(_.split("=")).map(x => (x(0).toLowerCase.trim, x(1).toLowerCase.trim)).toMap
header = header.split(",").map(x => if(kv.keySet.contains(x)) kv(x);else x).mkString(",")
```